# Свойство возвращающее индекс выбранного элемента в меню

Tags: c#, wpf

Если в ComboBox есть свойство *SelectedIndex*, то как называется такое в MenuItem? (перерыл msdn - не нашел(видимо слепой)).

Comment: Нет у MenuItem такого свойства, оно ему не нужно.

Comment: Тогда как реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на какой-либо элемент вызывался метод?

Comment: У MenuItem есть событие Click - вот к нему у привязывайте (самый естественный способ), только ваша функция должна соответствовать делегату этого события.